# Accessing document hierarchy with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Is there a way, in Cocoa, to access the object hierarchy of an HTML document, through UIWebView or otherwise? For example, I want to take an HTML file and pull out a list of all images (`<img>`), all links (`<a href>`), and so on, with their associated attributes (src="", href="", style=""... and so on).

Secondly, say I have an html page with an image with no style information associated with it (plain old `<img src="">` tag). Is it possible to, after the page has been rendered in said UIWebView, determine any inherited properties, and maybe even the size of it displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a). You can use this to run a script that finds the tags you're interested in, then returns the data you're interested in as a string. If you want to grab a lot of data at once then it's probably easiest to use JSON while you're passing it around. An example:

```
NSString *jsonString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var result = {}; var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); for (x = 0; x < imgs.length; x++) { result[x] = {'src': imgs[x].src, 'width': imgs[x].offsetWidth, 'height': imgs[x].offsetHeight}; } result = JSON.stringify(result);"];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *imgArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

So, now you have an `NSArray` with all the images an the attributes you were interested in. Note that `NSJSONSerialization` does require iOS 5 or OS X 10.7, though there are [third-party libraries](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) out there if you need to support earlier OS versions. (`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` goes back to iOS 2.0 and 10.2.7.)

Comment: Oh awesome! Haha that makes life so much easier for me, thanks!